# generating function for $\sum\limits_k \frac{x^k}{k^2}$?

Tags: generating-functions

Does anyone know the generating function $f$ of 
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k^2}$$

How can we get it? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're asking for a function which has the Taylor series in your question when expanded around $x=0$, the answer is the dilogarithm $\operatorname{Li}_2(x)$.

Answer (score 8):

If we differentiate we get $$ f'(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k-1}}{k}= -\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}$$ so $\displaystyle f(x) = \int^x_0 \frac{-\log(1-t)}{t} dt.$

Answer (score 5):

The [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm), $\operatorname {Li}_s$ is defined by the infinite series

$$\operatorname {Li}_s(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k^s}$$

Thus your sum is the polylogarithm of order 2.  $\operatorname {Li}_2$ is a special case fo the polylogarithm, called the [dilogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html)/[Spence's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function).

Answer (score 1):

You mean the generating function of the series given by $\tfrac{1}{k^2}$?

Plug "series x^k/k^2" it into [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) and it tells you it's the [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) for $s=2$.